# How to convert VIDEOHDR data to video stream using C++

Tags: c++, video, vfw

I have `VIDEOHDR` data ([detail for VIDEOHDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) which is got from camera by using `capSetCallbackOnVideoStream` and `capCaptureSequenceNoFile` function with C++

Now, I want to take `VIDEOHDR` data display as video on screen. How can I do it?

Comment: I think you should give a detail about what's the type of VIDEOHDR and video stream, and difference between them. so anyone else could provide some ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you got the video resolution Width x Height and image format (RGB24, YUYV, or ...) from another way as it'snt in the VIDEOHDR struct.

The VIDEOHDR struct you receive in the callback contain :    lpData and 
dwBufferLength

to display/render image you may need of an additional lib like SDL, OpenGL, OpenCV UI, MFC, QT

using 1 of those lib You can :
- create a window of Width x Height
- configure the window rendering to interpret data correctly depending of your capture format, RGB24 or another.
- anytime you get a new HDR in the callback, pass LpData to the render

but first choose your rendering framework and come back if you need help.